# How to disable summary for Tensorflow Estimator?

Tags: tensorflow, summary

I'm using Tensorflow-GPU 1.8 API on Windows 10. For many projects I use the tf.Estimator's, which really work great. It takes care of a bunch of steps including writting summaries for Tensorboard. But right now the 'events.out.tfevents' file getting way to big and I am running into "out of space" errors. For that reason I want to disable the summary writting or at least reduce the amount of summaries written.

Going along with that mission I found out about the RunConfig you can pass over at construction of tf.Estimator. Apparently the parameter 'save_summary_steps' (which by default is 200) controls the way summaries are wrtitten out. Unfortunately changing this parameter seems to have no effect at all. It won't disable (using None value) the summary or reducing (choosing higher values, e.g. 3000) the file size of 'events.out.tfevents'.

I hope you guys can help me out here. Any help is appreciated.

Cheers,
Tobs.

Answer (score 0):

I've observed the following behavior. It doesn't make sense to me so I hope we get a better answer:

When the `input_fn` gets data from `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` then the number of steps between saving events is the minimum of `save_summary_steps` and (*number of training examples* divided by *batch size*). That means it does it a minimum of once per epoch.

When the `input_fn` gets data from `tf.TextLineReader`, it follows `save_summary_steps` as you'd expect and I can give it a large value for infrequent updates.

Comment: You could also set `save_summary_steps` to `None`

Comment: That will just cause it to use the default value, won't it?